# stuck on svc webservice request not reach to server

Tags: ios, wcf, svc

I am calling this webservice from iOS code But when i am calling from same request in my iOS code it is not giving me the response. fatal error or response byte 0 received like this.

i check with server when i post from iOS code but the reason is my request not able to reach successfully on server.

Can any one have an idea about why my request not able to reach on server??

Comment: Where is your iOS code?

Answer (score 2):

- Here is my IOS code...

  ```
  -(IBAction)FindWords:(id)sender
   {

     NSString *sSOAPMessage = @"<HotelSearchRequest><LoginInfo><UserName>service@wakanow.com</UserName><Password>password</Password></LoginInfo><Search><CityName>Dubai City</CityName><CountryName>United Arab Emirates</CountryName><CheckIn>15-12-2013</CheckIn><CheckOut>18-12-2013</CheckOut><Rooms>1</Rooms><Pax><Room><RoomId>1</RoomId><Adults No=\"2\"/><Child No=\"1\"><Age>5</Age></Child></Room></Pax><Currency>NGN</Currency><Ratings></Ratings><MinPrice></MinPrice><MaxPrice></MaxPrice><HotelName></HotelName></Search></HotelSearchRequest>";

     NSLog(@"SOAP MSG : %@",sSOAPMessage);

     sSOAPMessage = (NSString *) CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)[sSOAPMessage mutableCopy], NULL, CFSTR(",!$'()*+;?\n\"<>#\t :/"),kCFStringEncodingUTF8));

     NSString *strRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://betahwcf.wakanow.com/SVCServices/WakanowHotelService.svc/HotelSearch=%@",sSOAPMessage];

     NSURL *sRequestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strRequest];

     NSLog(@"NSURL : %@",sRequestURL);

     NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:sRequestURL];

     NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

     if(theConnection)
     {
           self.conWebData = [NSMutableData data];
     }
     else
     {
          NSLog(@"Some error occurred in Connection");
     }
   }

  -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:   (NSURLResponse*)response
  {
        [self.conWebData setLength:0];
  }
  -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
  {

        [self.conWebData appendData:data];
  }
  -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
  {
        NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction");
  }
  -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection
  {
       NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [self.conWebData length]);

       NSString*theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[self.conWebData mutableBytes] length:[self.conWebData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      //Check That the response is in with proper Format or not
      //Print Response
     NSLog(@"%@",theXML);

     xmlParser= [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:self.conWebData];

    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
    [xmlParser parse];
   }
  ```